# find element at an absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you use jquery to get the element at a particular x, y coordinate? You can .offset and .position to find absolute and relative position using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you know the exact coordinates relative to the document:

```
function getElsAt(top, left){return $("body").find("*").filter(function(){return $(this).offset().top == top && $(this).offset().left == left})}
```

The other answer stops at the first overlay.