# in jQuery, select element that is within window of smaller div

Tags: jquery, position, coordinates, offset

I have an unordered list that is a child in a smaller parent div and is scrolled within the first div. How would I select the `<li>` that is currently visible within the first div's window?

What I have tried is using the jQuery offset coordinates of the parent container and elementFromPoint which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position)

```
xcoo = $('#menuholder1').offset().left;
ycoo = $('#menuholder1').offset().top;
clickedID = document.elementFromPoint(xcoo, ycoo).id;
```

However, this is returning the element one item higher. So I tried just adding to ycoo but then it returns nothing.

Does anyone have another solution to this? The page in question is http://do.right.by

Comment: your approach (asking the browser to find the element at a certain position) seems a little awkward to me. you know the height of each LI element, as well the scrollTop position of it's container, so you can calculate for yourself which element is at a certain position (in view), no?

Comment: agree with @schellmax  , code will be easier to read also. ALso look at `position()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this plugin to select visible elements: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/viewport

It adds the pseudo-selector `:in-viewport`, so you can select like this:

```
$("li:in-viewport")
```

To make it apply to a parent element rather than the window, get the modified source code here: https://gist.github.com/2979829

For the IIFE that looks like this

```
(function($, window) {
    //bunch of code...
})(jQuery, "#menuholder1");
```

#menuholder1 is the query that selects your parent element.

Comment: I found that plugin but would :in-viewport apply if the element is within the browser window but just not in the visible part of the parent div?

Comment: for me, it's returning all the li elements in the parent container. You can check the console log on the site.

Comment: sorry, modifying the source code very slightly fixes it. I posted an explanation.

Comment: hmm, promising but I am now getting undefined...does it have to be the immediate parent?

Comment: finally fixed! I forgot to use offset rather than scroll when switching from `window` to parent.

Comment: AMAZING!!! thank you so much, please see the desired effect on the site...clicking loads the submenu of the li into the menuholder2 div with ajax