# Show an element without "hitbox" (does not take mouse/touch input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to achieve is a kind of notification box (a `div` element). I would like to show it with some opacity. And I need the box to be "invisible" by the events. For example, if the box is on top of a button, I can still click the button through the box.

Some may suggest make it movable by the user, but the current UI does not allow me to do so.

Can it be achieved by any mean? HTML, CSS, Javascript and jQuery are all available.

My current notification box CSS:

```
.notification-box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 100vw;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css pointer events as noted in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914068/jquery-trigger-click-even-on-element-behind)

```
.notification-box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 100vw;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/RWbwzJ) showing it in action.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Works perfectly!

Comment: No problem! Can you mark it as the answer so other people looking for an answer know it worked?

Comment: Yes, marked. It didn't pass 15 mins when I commented.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a duplicate, but the answer to this question is also the answer to your question.

[jQuery - Trigger click even on element behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914068/jquery-trigger-click-even-on-element-behind)

> You can use the CSS
>   [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) property:
>
> > The CSS property `pointer-events` allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become
> >     the target of mouse events.
>
> ```
> #element {
>   pointer-events: none;
> }
> ```
>
> Or you can `trigger` the `click` event:
>
> ```
> $('#box').click(function(){
>    $('#target').trigger('click')
> })
> ```