# Find element within DOM at given (x,y), and trigger jQuery droppable on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-droppable

This is a two part question that I need some help with please.

1. if I only have an x,y position in a page, how can I get the element that sits at that position within the page using `javascript/jQuery`? Is it possible? Bonus points for efficiency, albeit relative to the complexity of a given DOM...
2. assuming its a`Droppable element`, how I can trigger the`Droppable event` upon it, and pass it the element that was dragged to that position?

Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position

Comment: Ahh brill, I was searching but couldn't find a question for it! Thanks. Have you any input on the second part?