# Simulate touchpad for the web

Tags: jquery, simulate, kiosk

I develop the web site app which will running on the Kiosk device. [image]

[image]

I'd like make the virtual touchpad, let a handicap could click, drag and do more things on my kiosk from that touchpad.
Please see my screenshot to understand my idea.

If anyone provide me the jquery library or something similar to handle it I would appreciate that.

I've found the source https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate/wiki but it could not help

Comment: I have no experience with [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) but if you check out their [Event logger](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/examples/events.html) you should be able to translate local gestures into global virtual mouse movements. (deltaX, deltaY seems the most appropiate data). Good luck!

Comment: @AmazingDreams Thank you. Capturing and manipulating with gesture would be the function that should be applied, but the problem is creating the virtual touchpad. I have idea about calculate the small div(touch pad) and scale to the corresponding coordinator on big screen, but the problem about location of the object user clicks on.
There still has many questions beside that, I just hope someone know a library or something exist to treat the kind of thing like this.

Comment: ah: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position

Comment: The question is still living. Any idea else? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that this is an old question but it is one of the things that came up when I was google searching for any canned solutions to simulate a touch pad pointing device in a mobile browser based web application.

I recently published this code on github.
https://github.com/mmiscool/JS-virtual-Touchpad

It overlays a virtual touchpad over an iframe and provides a simulated mouse cursor to send the typical events associated with common mouse interaction to  the application in the iframe.

It provides a virtual mouse pointer and lets you interact with the application as if you had a real mouse attached to the device when used in a mobile browser.

Comment: After 15 yrs, finally you bring the truly solution. Thank mmiscool.