# how to get html elements from specific height using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

how to get content between 1300 and 4200 heights (scrollTop) values using jquery

some times the start and end values may be different

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/position/  and   http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I strongly believe there's a better way if you explain what you're trying to do...

Comment: This question has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/using-jquery-to-find-an-element-at-a-particular-position

Comment: i have more than four articles in html page (with no fixed size) when am scrolling up i need to get the content of the currently located article

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet which looks for elements whose top offsets are between 1300 and 4200 pixels, saving them to an element array `arr`:

```
var items = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var arr = [];
$.each(items, function (i, ele) {
    var offset = $(ele).offset();
    if (offset && offset.top >= 1300 && offset.top <= 4200) {
        arr.push(ele);
    }
});
```

It relies on jQuery's [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function, which does not take into account any margins/padding on the body element. Results may also be off if the browser is not at 100% zoom (there are more details in the jQuery documentation).

I hope it's useful as a starting point.